# How to link against cython numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython

I have an application that uses `pandas` and `cvxpy` to solve an optimization problem. I have cython setup via `pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs': np.get_include()})` and in my modules I have:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
```

When I run the program, I can see gcc compiling the code. However, when I optimize with `%prun`, this is the result:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   13   95.403    7.339   95.627    7.356 decomp.py:270(eigh)
   39    7.826    0.201    8.968    0.230 numeric.py:2319(within_tol)
   13    5.756    0.443    5.756    0.443 {built-in method _ecos.csolve}
   13    4.805    0.370    5.118    0.394 decomp.py:118(eig)
  729    4.714    0.006    4.714    0.006 {built-in method _cvxcore.LinOp_set_dense_data}
    1    2.398    2.398  138.383  138.383 <string>:1(<module>)
   13    2.073    0.159   97.705    7.516 quad_form.py:147(decomp_quad)
   91    1.140    0.013    1.140    0.013 {built-in method builtins.abs}
   26    0.994    0.038    0.994    0.038 {method 'dot' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    1    0.571    0.571    4.045    4.045 {pandas._libs.reduction.reduce}
```

As you can see, `decompy.py:eigh` is the function that's taking the most time so I'd like to cythonize this if possible. It is part of `scipy` which I'm guessing should already be compiled when I use `cimport`, but because it's being called within `cvxpy` I'm guessing it's using the python version rather than the cython version. Do I need to cythonize `cvxpy` to make it use cython `numpy`?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Cython cannot change which functions are called, to change that you have to change the functions themselves. Maybe a minimal example would make it clearer?

Comment: Sorry for the poorly worded question. I've rephrased my question to hopefully be clearer. Essentially, `cvxpy` is calling a function in `scipy` that looks like is the python implementation. So I'm wondering if there's a way to make it use cython's version?

Comment: `eig` in decomp.py is just a small wrapper which calls LAPACK-eig implementation. So the lion share of the time is probably spent in the LAPACK-function. Cythonizing it will not help at all.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you're right, I tried switching `pyimport=True` which led python to basically try and compile everything and didn't observe a much improvement in speed.